# Identity Framework Experience Definition

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are working on exploring the capabilities of Azure AD B2C.  I followed the documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom

What I am not finding is the definition for the XML elements in the policy files. It seems like others are finding information on what the elements. I fear I'm just missing it.

**QUESTION:   Where can I find detailed specs on the XML Elements and what they do?**

For example:

What is a "OrchestrationStep" What does it do? What are the options for configuring Steps?

What is a TechnicalProfile?  etc etc etc....

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best, but beta, collection of documentation for custom policies can be found at the following repository:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Documentation

This documentation was drafted for the public preview of "Azure AD B2C Advanced" which, now, is known as Identity Experience Framework.